# Debug browser lockup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

I have an intermittent problem with my AngularJS app. When it happens, on the page loading, the browser locks up completely. I can't access developer tools or click anything. When I debug in Webstorm, I try to pause the process when the lock up is happening but that becomes unresponsive also.

Is there a good debugging technique to pinpoint where the lock up is happening? Nothing is written to console due to lock up so that peppering with comments idea doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: While browser is executing javascript, it is locked. And I doupt this can be changed. But looking in code and find places that may take lot of time should be relatively easy, then you may add some logging to console.

Comment: This seemed to be an issue with Chrome. I think I was on 67, but my code hasn't changed and the problem no longer happens. Guessing it was a minor update that fixed it.